# Is it possible to emulate Mifare Ultralight?

Tags: rfid

Is it possible to emulate mifare ultralight disregarding the specification, so that electronic tickets can be infinitely used? Mifare Ultralight has 16 pages with 4 bytes each. There are control bytes for the OTP page. The terminal can check those bytes and refuse the ticket, but if it's a hardware implementation then the standard can be disregarded and the terminal fooled. Also this could open a door to understanding the other data pages that are probably used for timestamps. So, is it possible to emulate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it can be emulated. There is no fundamental reason that this "slow" protocol cannot run on a SDR system such as USRP.

But, you may have to design the RF front-end to reproduce the way a passive RFID tag works. Definitely not rocket science. The issue is the have the full specs of MIFARE Ultralight in order to know how to emulate.

Comment: It just that I've seen a defcon talk and the guy says that every tag can be "replayed". BTW, could you explain SDR system and USRP

Comment: SDR is "software defined radio" and USRP is a hardware module "low cost" (by low cost I mean ~700$ for the smallest module) that does the RF work. http://www.ettus.com/

Comment: Sorry to comment after so much time, but I just went over the libnfc docs and there's an api for emulating Mifare Ultralight, but I can't find an example, can you help?